# How do you hide your browser advertising fingerprint?

Tags: privacy, user-tracking, browser-extensions, fingerprinting

How do you hide your browser finger print from advertising networks without disabling javascript?
Is there a browser extension that can help mask unique browser fingerprint? Browser finger print can be things like available system fonts, gpu type, pci ids, webrtc ip, extensions, screen resolution etc.

How do you make your browser non unique fingerprintable hidable on?
https://www.amiunique.org/

I am concerned that even if I use a vpn for privacy advertising networks can still track you through browser fingerprinting. How do you hide your browser from finger printing?

Comment: A non-unique fingerprint is apparently a browser which uses common settings/ has same fonts installed, which usually comes at the cost of security itself. For example, if you harden your Firefox install your fingerprint will become more unique, but also possibly more secure against exploits, because for example the next big upcoming exploit is in WebAssembly and you disabled it. So the question would be - do you really want that?

Comment: If you're using Firefox please refer to https://security.stackexchange.com/a/221464

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to avoid fingerprinting. The browser that currently best *resists* fingerprinting is [Tor Browser](https://torproject.org/), which uses a modified version of Firefox. If you don't wish to use Tor, then you can use regular Firefox with the configuration setting `privacy.resistFingerprinting` set to `true`. This will help to some extent. Some advice, such as Sir Muffington's [answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/221464/106285), can reduce the number of fingerprinting vectors, but be aware that any significant changes to your browser configuration can *itself* be a fingerprint, albeit a rather weak one. It's just something to be aware of.